# Snap.js JQuery conflict?

Tags: jquery, snap.js, ratchet-bootstrap

I'm having trouble accessing my `div` elements with jQuery after implementing `snap.js` in my Ratchet project, does anyone know why and how can I fix this?

```
document.getElementById('mydivId').innerHTML   //THIS WORKS
$('#mydivId').html()  //THIS DOESN'T WORK
```

I've included the jquery.js and implemented $(document).ready(function(){});

I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ready' of null"

Comment: Have you included `jquery.js`? Is the code in a `$(document).ready(fn)` block? Any errors in the console? Some more detail in the question would help.

Comment: yes, I've included jquery.js, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ready' of null" in the console

Comment: And the other issues...?

Comment: No other issues, just zero jquery functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this,instead of $ use jQuery,so renaming anything.

```
 jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
   // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
 });
```

**Other alternative**

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
j( "div p" ).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found what the issue is... turns out Snap.js also uses the $ alias like Jquery, so that's what creates the conflict. In the script tag on the index.html i renamed all occurrences of $ and changed it to $$.

```
    // Helper
    $$ = function(id){
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }, 
                ....
                $$('right-drawer').classList.add('active-drawer');
                ....
                $$('toggle-left').addEventListener('click', function(){
                    snapper.open('left');
                 });
```

and so forth.